# How can I run two instances of a command in a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to write a docker-compose file that references a Dockerfile in the same directory. The purpose of this docker-compose file is to run the command `htop` when I build my Dockerfile image it runs htop perfectly fine and I can pass arguments to an entry point. Whenever I go to try to run docker-compose up it starts the htop instances but then exits immediately. Is there anyway I can open two terminals or two containers and each container be running an htop instance?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER anon

RUN apk --no-cache add \
    htop

ENTRYPOINT ["htop"]
```

docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

```
services:
  htop_one:
    build: .
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
  htop_two:
    build: .
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd expect this container to run a single command, `htop HTOP`.  What behavior are you actually expecting?

Comment: @DavidMaze I thought running ` ./docker && docker-compose up ` would allow me to run two services at once. Two instances of htop in this case. I think my compose file is where the problem is, and currently I cant even get the container to run at all. See error above

Comment: Why two?  Is the Docker daemon actually running?

Comment: @DavidMaze disregard my last comment, I was able to fix my error above and now I am dealing with docker-compose throwing Error opening terminal: unknown.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by running `htop` inside a container?

Comment: I am just following a tutorial given to me to familiarize myself with docker, but I was confused by the wording considering I know how htop works but not how docker works. @Z4-tier

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is a terminal incompatibility. You run this from a terminal that is unknown to the software in the docker image.

The second problem, of the containers exiting immediately, could be fixed by using a proper init like [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER anon

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        htop\
        tini

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  htop_one:
    build: .
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
    command: ["top"]

  htop_two:
    build: .
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
    command: ["top"]
```

To run the two services in parallel, as they each need a controlling terminal, you would run, from two different terminals:

```
docker-compose up htop_one
```

and

```
docker-compose up htop_two
```

respectively.

Note this is creating two containers from the same image. Each docker-compose service is, of course, run in a separate container.

If you'd like to run commands in the same container, you could start a service like

```
docker-compose up myservice
```

and run commands in it:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> htop
```

from different terminals, as many times as you'd like.

Not also that you can determine `container_name` via `docker container ls` and you can also set the container name from the docker-compose file,

Comment: I would like to have two instances of htop runinng which are built off of my Dockerfile. I would like htop to not exit immediately so I can monitor it. I changed my docker-compose file a little bit after reading your post and edited the main post above.

Comment: How do you expect two instances of htop to run in the same terminal (I'm not trying to be funny, just trying to understand what you expect/want)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified they dont have to be in the same terminal. To answer your question I am not sure either I am extremely new to docker so I was seeing if this is possible. My thought process was I have a Dockerfile that starts an htop, I could use docker-compose to essentially call it twice and have two instances of it running. (two different terminal windows or tabs)

Comment: You could call `docker run -it ...`  from two different terminals, or you could run `docker-compose up htop_one` and `docker-compose up htop_two`. I'll try to determine why htop is exiting immediately,

Comment: okay that makes sense to me, is there a way to use docker so I could just run the docker-compose up command and have it spin up those two terminals? (This is where I am super green with docker haha)

Comment: Oh. No I don't think so, because the terminal(s) are running on your host machine. You cannot (and should not!) control software on your host. There might be fancy ways to somehow share your terminal with the two sessions... but this is probably misleading.

Comment: And, @dmc94, are you actually trying to run the two htops in the _same_ container?

Comment: Okay I see, if thats the case then yes I think I would want them running in the same container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205358/discussion-between-petre-and-dmc94).

Answer (score 0):

On the issue of your `htop` command exiting, thus causing your docker container to exit.

This is normal behavior for docker containers.  The `htop` is most likely exiting because it can't figure out the terminal when in a docker image, as @petre mentioned.  When you run your docker image, be sure to use the `-i` option for an interactive session.

```
docker run -it MYIMAGE htop
```

To change the docker auto-exit behavior, do something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
CMD exec /bin/sh -c "trap : TERM INT; (while true; do MYCOMMAND; sleep 1000; done) & wait"
```

This runs your `MYCOMMAND` command over and over again, but allows the container to be stopped when you want.    You can run a `docker exec -it MYCONTAINER sh` when you want to do other things in that same container.

Also, if you happen to be running docker in Windows, then prefix a `winpty` to the docker command like: `winpty docker ...` so it can get the terminal correct.